# How to upload some media test content into Windows Phone emulator?

Tags: windows-phone

I have VS2012 windows phone emulator that works just fine. I can develop and debug.

The question is how to upload test content to the emulator? I need a few songs in the emulator  media library to debug my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately you cannot do that in the emulator... you need an actual phone...

Comment: Can I debug an actual phone?

Comment: yes, sure (assuming that you are a registered developer = paid $100 to microsoft)... you need to dev unlock your phone, then start zune and instead of start in emulator you select start on device and you can debug the same way as on the emulator...

Comment: Got it. BTW, it's one time one year free with MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload files to your emulator with windows phone power tools.Connect emulator and put file where you want.
Check this link:
[Wp Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just sign into SkyDrive and grab from there?
Also this 7.0 approach to deploying files to the emulator might still work: http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation

Comment: To access SkyDrive I need to sign in Microsoft account. It does not work on emulator. You cant sign in. I cant even buy any content, because it requires MS account as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get with your local developer evangelist to get a test device. You can use this app to find out who that is - http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=30db0bac-e968-4e50-8205-30adf19fb5b9.